# Azure "Microsoft Imagine" subscription JAR build limitation

Tags: java, azure, azure-devops

I have a Azure "Microsoft Imagine" subscription. I'm trying to crate a release pipeline for a public project in the Azure DevOps. The project is Java Based. But I'm getting this and unable to proceed.

[image]

I have another project with NodeJS and that does shows my Imagine subscription.

[image]

I'm not sure what's the issue. I'm new to Azure and Azure DevOps.

Edit:
Additional Question -

After following the steps by Alvin Zhao I was able to get the subscription but build to JAR is disabled. Is it due to my subscription limitations or is there a way to enable it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is the [Azure Resource Manager service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#azure-resource-manager-service-connection) that we can use in release pipelines to target an Azure subscription for app services deployment.

You may check in your public project if the ARM service connection exists in `Project Settings -> Pipelines -> Service connections`and you may share the `Microsoft Imagine` ARM service connection from the `other project` with the `public project`.
[image]

If you are the owner of this Azure subscription, Application administrator of the AAD tenant that the subscription comes from and you the project administrator of the public project, you may consider creating a new ARM service connection automatically as well.

For more information, see [Connect to Microsoft Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Thank You I was able to get the subscription in my other projects following your steps. Can you can also answer my additional related question if possible.

Comment: Hi @SudiptaBiswas, Regarding the follow-up question, may I assume that you are unable to list the app name under the ARM svc cnn (`Microsoft Imagine xxxx`)? Can you double check if the `App Type` is correct? If possbile, would you post a new thread to help understand the issue `build to JAR is disabled`?

Comment: As far as I know Azure DevOps itself as an auntomation tool for deployment shouldnot limit WAR/JAR deployment; hence, I suspect the issue was caused by the app service configurations. To narrow down the root cause, you may also test with the [Azure CLI command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-deploy) `az webapp deploy` to see if the issue persists. I would suggest you post another thread to share more information on your app configurations with the `app services` tag to engage more specialists from respective subcommunity.

Comment: In case you would simply enable the `Deploy Jar to Azure App Service` task, you may right click on the task and click on `Enable selected task(s)`.

Comment: Silly me, right on the task and click on "Enable selected task(s)" solved the issue.